# Texture becomes white when I zoom out

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[image]
[image]

Currently I am making an animation with running model.

I used Mixamo to rig my human model which has clothes on it.
After I rigged, then the texture becomes white when I zoom out.
If I zoom in very close, the texture looks fine.

I thought this might be okay if I render it (EEVEE), but it still has white dots.
And I also fixed the size of the pants, because I thought its too tight for the body.But it was all the same, I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Are you using a Subdivision Surface Modifier with Adaptive Subdivision enabled on your character's legs (or pants) by any chance?

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: Can you show an image that shows how the material is created?

Comment: I added a photo of the material please check. I made this pants on Marvelous designer and put image texture on it.

Comment: No, i didn't use any modifier. I sculpted body and pants model a little. Could this be the problem? :((

Comment: No, i didn't use any modifier. I sculpted body and pants model a little. Could this be the problem? :((

Comment: The first material in the list is white. What is that for? Do you need it? If not, delete it and see if that fixes the problem. I suspect the base material is showing through for some reason. Could be wrong, but that was my initial thought. Also, does the same thing happen in Cycles?